# Cannot get css border colors to change on hover

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get the background color of the 'About' button to change to yellow and the border color to change to blue when it is hovered over.
Currently only a tiny rectangle around the text changes to yellow on hover and i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.
The buttons are required to be made using an unordered list with the inline display.
Here is a picture of the exercise for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEFh0.jpg

Thank you for any suggestions or help.

[Thank you all for the answers, im unable to upvote as i have less than 15 rep]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Exercise 5</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

        a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


        #buttons li{
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 30px 66px 9px 66px;
            border-color: violet violet orange yellow;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 5px 10px 20px 30px;
            box-shadow: -15px 5px 20px 5px black; /*1px left right, 2px up down */
            padding: 30px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .about:hover {
            background-color: yellow;
            border-color: yellow;
            color: blue;

        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <ul id="buttons">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the about class doesn't even exist in your HTML bro

Comment: We havent used this about class yet but the answer below worked without it, im not able to select it as the answer for a couple of mins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added the about class to HTML and targeted it in css using `#buttons li.about:hover`

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#buttons li {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px 66px 9px 66px;
  border-color: violet violet orange yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 10px 20px 30px;
  box-shadow: -15px 5px 20px 5px black;
  /*1px left right, 2px up down */
  padding: 30px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#buttons li.about:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Exercise 5</title>

</head>

<body>


  <ul id="buttons">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#buttons li.about:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the list item for the background and stroke and use the parent and `a` tag to target the color of the element.

Also, I do not see a class for `.about` in your html either.

```css
#buttons li:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: blue;
}

#buttons li:hover a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#buttons li {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px 66px 9px 66px;
  border-color: violet violet orange yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 10px 20px 30px;
  box-shadow: -15px 5px 20px 5px black;
  /*1px left right, 2px up down */
  padding: 30px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#buttons li:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: blue;
}

#buttons li:hover a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="buttons">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```